# ¿Cómo obtengo un objeto json dentro de una llamada fetch para usarla en otro lugar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
var countries;
fetch(url).then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => {
                countries = JSON.parse(data); //Dentro de esta funcion tengo el dato perfectamente
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e));

console.log(countries); //Tipo indefinido, no reconoce el dato.
```

¿Cómo puedo usar esta variable fuera del fetch?

---

¿Y como puedo "pintar" por pantalla desde dentro de esta misma función?

Pongo aquí mi ejemplo:

```
render() {

    fetch(url).then(r => r.json())
        .then(data => {
            dato= JSON.parse(data);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));

    return (
        <div> (dato) </div>
    );
 }
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 4):

No puedes usarla "fuera" del fetch, lo que has de hacer es llamar desde ese punto al código que va a hacer uso de ese valor:

```
//var countries; --> no es necesario
fetch(url).then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => {
                let countries = JSON.parse(data);
                useCountries(countries);
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e));

function useCountries(c) {
    console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El código asíncrono se caracteriza por anotarse para ser ejecutado en un momento a futuro. Primero se agenda, luego se ejecuta. ¿A qué voy con esto?

Lo primero que hiciste fue definir una variable:

```
var countries;
```

Al no asignarle un valor, `countries` es `undefined`. Luego de definir eso, utilizás la función `fetch()`. Lo que hacés en esta parte del código es específicar la acción a hacer, hacerla, y finamente especifica qué hacer luego (esto último lo hacés con los `then`):

```
fetch(url)   // hacer esto, y luego (el momento lo decide el engine js), hacer lo que hay en el then.
.then(r =>  // Esto va a ser ejecutado en algún momento, no se sabe cuándo.
            r.json())
            .then(data => {
                countries = JSON.parse(data);
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Ahora bien, esta parte `console.log(countries);` es ejecutada inmediatamente después de agendarse las acciones a realizar luego de haber 'fetcheado' la URL. En otras palabras:

- Declarás `countries`
- Hacés un fetch a una URL, y cuando eso termine en algún momento, asignás un valor a `countries`
- Mostrás `countries` (sigue siendo `undefined`).
- Cuando el fetch termine, se asigna el valor a `countries` (acá deja de ser `undefined`).

Es un cambio en la manera de organizar el código lo que vas a tener que afrontar si venís de programar de manera síncrona. También recordá identar mejor tu código:

```
fetch(url)
.then(r => r.json())
.then(data => countries = JSON.parse(data))
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Mucho mas legible :)

Respecto a cómo mostrar eso en pantalla, depende dónde lo quieras mostrar. Podés usar alertas (vía función `alert`), o podés poner el valor dentro de un objeto HTML:

```
render() {

    fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
          // dato sólo existe dentro de este then.
         dato= JSON.parse(data);
     })
     .catch(e => console.log(e));

    return (
        <div> (dato) </div>
    );
 }
```

No estoy seguro de ese "return", pero hasta dónde comprendo, simplemente es un error, el  va a ser evaluado como JS y no como HTML. Además, la variable 'dato' existe sólo dentro del `then` dónde realizás esa acción. Si querés poner los datos recibidos en un elemento HTML para que sea visible, deberías hacer algo como esto:

HTML:

```
<div id = 'test'></div>
```

JS:

```
'use strict';

const div = document.getElementById('test');
fetch(url)
.then(data => div.innerHTML = data )
```

Ante cualquier duda, comentame e intento editar. También, podés aprovechar otros features de ecma6, como `const` y `let`.